# Classifying the central product HK of two cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let group $H$ be a direct product of cyclic groups $C_1$ and $C_2$ of order $p$ and $p^2$ respectively. Let $D=\{x\in H\mid \text{ord}(x)\leq p \}$. D is generated by $C_1$ and subgroup $E$ of $C_2$ of order $p$. Let $K$ be a group which isomorphic to H, and let $F\subset K$ be a group which corresponds to $D$. Let $\phi:D \to F$ be any isomorphism. By identifying D with F by $\phi$,  we got a central product $HK$. If the generator of $\phi(E)$ is p-th power in $K$, then $HK \cong C_2\times C_1\times C_1$. If not, $HK \cong C_2\times C_2$.

How can I prove the last two statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$The main point should be the following.

Write $C_{1} = \Span{c_{1}}$, $C_{2} = \Span{c_{2}}$, and write $K = \Span{ d_{1}, d_{2} }$, where the order of $d_{i}$ is $p^{i}$.

Then if $\phi(c_{2}^{p}) = d_{2}^{p}$ (which we can assume, without loss of generality), then the element $c_{2} d_{2}^{-1}$ of $HK$ has order $p$.

Comment: Oh, so you mean that $HK \cong \langle c_2d_2^{-1}\rangle\times \langle c_1\rangle\times \langle c_2\rangle$ ?

Comment: That's it, yes!